# How to connect to my database on k8s using the "command" instruction of a readinessProbe?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, yaml

Friends, I am trying to implement a readinessProbe here like this:

```
readinessProbe:  
  exec:
    command: ["mysql", "-u root", "-p $(MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)", "SHOW DATABASES;"]
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 2
    timeoutSeconds: 1
```

But I am getting an access denied error: **ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ' root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

When I exec inside my pod, I can connect to the database normally so I think I am doing something wrong by the execution the the connection commands. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd guess that either `"-u", "root"` need to be separate options, or `"-uroot"` as one option can't have a space.  (Does it say `' root'` with a space in the error message?)

Comment: Yes, David, in the logs It was saying '  root' indeed. Thanks for the hint. Still learning how these things work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me like this:

```
readinessProbe:
   exec:
      command:
      - "bash" 
      - "-c"
      - "mysql --user=${MYSQL_USER} --password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD} --execute=\"SHOW DATABASES;\""
```

But I still don't know how to "translate" this if I want to use brackets.

Answer (score 1):

When you use JSON-array syntax for `command:` and similar options, you specify exactly how the command is split up into "words".  So when the option says

```yaml
command: [..., "-u root", ...]
```

That is a single option containing an embedded space (I might say aloud "dash u space root").  In an interactive shell it'd be the equivalent of quoting the option `mysql '-u root' ...`.

From your error message, it looks like the `mysql` client tool interprets the space as part of the user name; you don't want that.  Either split it yourself into two separate options, or remove the space between the option and the argument.

```yaml
command: [..., "-u", "root", ...]
command: [..., "-uroot", ...]
```